# Using dll references depending on device in windows ce

Tags: c#, dll, compact-framework

I am creating a barcode scanning  project using c# and compact framework 2.0 on windows ce devices from CHD and Honeywell. for the project to work on both devices i needed to create two separate projects because they need different dll refreneces. but I was wondering if it possible to reference a dll that is needed only when the right device is detected, for example, cetrain functions only get called if the divice is CHD and others if the device is Honeywell.

Comment: will project compile if only one set of dll's is referenced?

Comment: If you can determine a device type on run-time it is possible to load said references. Take a look at [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/528178/Load-DLL-From-Embedded-Resource). Also you can create your own wrapper for both references and  inside that wrapper make calls depending on device type.

Comment: @raidensan: i assume this code will not work on Compact Framework

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have done it in the past with pocketMEF, an abstraction layer and different 'plugin' DLLs for the different hardware.

An article is at http://www.hjgode.de/wp/2012/02/16/mobile-development-compact-framework-managed-extension-framework-mef/ and this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/29443287/1479943

Answer (score 1):

If you want an example specific for barcode scanners, take a look at the [OpenNETCF Scanner Compatibility library on CodePlex](https://scanner.codeplex.com/).  It shows specifically how to load the right scanner reference libraries depending on which hardware you're using and allows a single UI codebase to use only one call to get the scanner object.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this question.  I posted an answer there that may work for your situation as well:

[How to load an assembly from byte array in compact framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29417154/how-to-load-an-assembly-from-byte-array-in-compact-framework/29432511#29432511)

In summary, if you can define a common abstraction of your scanning then you can dynamically load using the Assembly class the device-specific dll you need to use.